# Using Google Font in SVG?

Tags: css, svg, fonts, google-font-api

I am having a lot of trouble getting my SVGs to display the Google font, Lato. I read  similar questions about this and tried to implement what I learned. For what it's worth, the font *does* display on my computer (because I have the Google font installed), but it does not elsewhere.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 360 260" style="enable-background:new 0 0 360 260;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato');
    .st0{fill:#ECF0F1;}
    .st1{fill:none;}
    .st2{fill:#34495E;stroke:#34495E;stroke-width:0.25;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st3{'Lato', sans-serif;}
    .st4{font-size:35px;}
    .st5{fill:none;stroke:#34495E;stroke-width:3;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st6{font-weight: 'lighter';}
    .st7{fill:#34495E;}
</style>
<title>hangman_game</title>
<rect class="st0" width="360" height="260"/>
<rect x="-8.7" y="207.2" class="st1" width="377.4" height="33"/>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 12.5111 232.7089)" class="st3 st4 st7" font-weight="300">Colombia Infographics</text>
<g>
    <g>
        <g>
            <path class="st5" d="M117.4,133c0.3-0.8,1.2-1.8,1.3-2.5c0.3-1.2-0.5-2.1-0.3-3.2c0.3-1.9,2.4-3.1,2.5-5.2c1.2-0.6,1-0.1,1.9-1.3
                c0.5,0.6,1.4,0.6,1.8,0.9c0.9-1.3,1.9-0.6,3.2-1.6c1.2-0.9,1.5-2.4,2.4-3.5c2.4-2.8,5.4-5,7.6-7.9c-0.9-0.8-1.9-1.3-3.1-1.4
                c0.1-0.8-0.3-1.9-0.1-2.8c-0.4,0.5-1.4,0.8-1.8,1.2c-2-3.1-1-2,0-4.9c0.4-1.2,0.8-3,0.8-4.4c-0.1-2.2-4.1-8.4,1.3-7.5
                c0.2-0.8,0.1-2-0.3-2.7c-1-0.4-1.9-0.6-3-0.7c-0.5-3.1,3.4-2.5,1.1-5.5c-0.2-0.2-1.5-0.1-2.1-0.7c-0.8-0.8-1-1.9-1.3-3
                c-0.8-2.6-0.9-5.2,0.6-7.1c0.5-0.6,1.6-0.5,2.3-1.5c0.7-0.8,0.9-2.5,1.4-3.5c-1.9-1.3-1.9-6.5,1.3-5.6c1.5,0.4,0.5,1.4,1.3,2.4
                c0.2,0.2,1.4,0.3,1.5,0.7c0,0.1,0.1,1.7,0.1,1.7c0.4,1-1.7,1.4,0.9,2.1c1.9,0.5,2.4-0.3,2.2-2.3c-0.2-2.3-3.2-3.5-1.5-6.1
                c4,0.3,3.9-3.3,7.1-5.1c2.9-1.6,6.9-1.6,5.9-6.2c-1.3-0.2-1.9-0.1-2.5,1.1c-0.2-1.8,1.2-3.5,2.2-4.9c0.9-1.3,1.6-3.8,2.4-4.8
                c3-3.4,6.1-2.6,9.8-2.4c-0.7,0.8-1.2,1.7-1.5,2.7c0.5,0.4,1.2,0.6,1.8,0.6c1.1-2.5,1.5-3.4,1.7-6.2c1.8-0.1,2.7-1.2,4.4-1.6
                s3.6,0.2,5.4-0.1c3.7-0.5,6-2.9,9.3-4.4c-0.2-0.7,0-1.4-0.5-2.1c1.1-1.2,5.1-2.6,6.5-3.1c2.7-0.8,5.9-0.3,6.9,2.4
                c-2.2,1.5-5.6,1.6-7.6,3.1s-2.6,3.9-4.9,6c-3.3,3.1-8.6,7.8-8.6,12.7c0,1.2,0.7,2.4,0.3,3.8c-0.3,1.1-2.2,2.9-2.1,3.7
                c0.3,2.4,1.9,0.2,2.8,0.9c1.1,0.9,1.2,2.2,1.8,3.5c1,2.4,3.3,4.9,4.1,7.4c0.7,2.3-0.8,4.9,0.7,6.8c1.6,1.9,6.9,3.8,9.3,3.8
                c1.3-2.6,2.7,0,4,0.1c1.4,0.1,2.5-1.1,4.1-0.9c2.8,0.3,7.3,4.4,9.3,6.1c1,0.9,3.2,3.8,4.4,3.9c0.9,0.1,1.5-1.3,2.5-1.3
                c1.3,0,1.7,1.1,2.8,1.3c1.9,0.3,3.1-0.7,5-1c1.6-0.2,3.3,0.6,5,0c0.3,2.3,3.7,2.6,3.5,5.3c-0.2,2.1-3.8,4.6-5.9,4.4
                c-1,2,0.4,2.2,0.6,3.4c0.2,1.6-0.1,3-0.1,4.6c0,2.7,0,6.3,0.9,9.1c0.3,1,1.7,1.7,1.7,3.4c0,1.4-0.7,2.5-1.3,3.8
                c-0.5,0.9-2.2,2.8-1.6,4.1c0.6,1.3,1.8,1.2,2.8,0c3.1,2.5,3.2,2.8,3.7,6.8c0.2,2.2,0.8,4.8,0.6,7.5c-1.2-1.8-1.4-6.2-3-7.5
                c-2.4-2-4.4,0.7-6.6,1c-1.4,0.2-2.5-0.4-4-0.1c-1.1,0.3-2.3,1.1-3.6,1.3c-2.9,0.4-6.1-0.6-9,0.3c-0.4,1.3-0.5,3.2,0.3,4.4
                c0.9,1.3,2,0.5,2.8,1.2c1.4,1.3,3,4.1,1,5.3c1.2,0,2.2,0.4,2.7,1.3c-3.3,2.7-2.9-0.6-5.4-0.4c-1,0.1-2,1.8-2.7,2.3
                c-1.9,1.4-1.4-1-2,1.8c-0.7,3.6,1.5,3.9,3.5,5.6c1.7,1.5,2.5,4.1,3,6.1c1.6,5.7,1.1,14-2,19c-1.6,2.5-1.6,3.7-2.2,6.6
                c-0.4,1.7-1,5.1-2.9,6c0-0.6-0.5-1.7-0.4-2.5c-1.7-0.3-2.6,0.6-4.3,0.5c-0.9-0.9-0.1-0.8-1.6-1.3c1.7-3.6,5.5-8.1,5.9-12.1
                c-0.4,0.2-1,0.2-1.5,0.6c-1.2-1.6-1.8-2.9-3.8-4c-0.3,0.4-0.9,0.8-1.2,1.1c-0.2-3.1-2.9-0.9-4.7-0.5c-1.4,0.3-1.1,0.3-3,0
                c-1.4-0.2-2.2-0.9-3.7-0.7c-1.7,0.3-2.8,1.8-4.6,1.8c-0.6,0-2.4-0.6-3.2-0.6c-1.6,0-5.4,1.5-5.3-1.2c2.3-0.8,1.8-2,0.6-3.4
                c-0.3-0.4-1.9-0.1-2.1-0.4c-0.7-0.9,0-1.9-0.4-2.8c-0.6-1.5-0.8-2.6-2.5-3.5s-3.2,0.1-4.6-1.4c0.2,0.1,0.5,0.3,0.7,0.3
                c-1.5-1.2-2.4-1.9-3.3-3.5c-1-1.7-1.3-3.8-3.2-4.9c-3.1-1.9-7.2-0.9-9.5-4.4c0.3-0.1,0.8-0.3,1.1-0.4c-1.7-1-10.7-3.4-8.1,1.6
                c-1.5-0.3-3.2-0.1-4.6-0.7c-1.3-0.5-1.9-1.9-3.5-2.4c-1-0.3-3.6,0.5-4.4,0c-1.8-1.4,0.8-2.7,0-4c-0.8-1.4-2.9-0.8-4.1-1.2
                c-1-0.4-2.7-1.5-3.7-2c-2-1.3-4-4.5-6.5-4.7c0.8,1-0.4,0.8-0.4,1.6"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Note, the SVG was generated by Illustrator then I changed the styling and added in the google font in the style bracket. Is something going wrong with the XML tag in the beginning?

https://jsfiddle.net/8h14px69/

Comment: Note: I realize some of the CSS classes defined in the style tag are not being used, I was just experimenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply missing `font-family` in the `.st3` class.

It should be

```
.st3{font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;}
```

instead of

```
.st3{'Lato', sans-serif;}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 360 260" style="enable-background:new 0 0 360 260;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato');
 .st0{fill:#ECF0F1;}
 .st1{fill:none;}
 .st2{fill:#34495E;stroke:#34495E;stroke-width:0.25;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st3{font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;}
 .st4{font-size:35px;}
 .st5{fill:none;stroke:#34495E;stroke-width:3;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st6{font-weight: 'lighter';}
 .st7{fill:#34495E;}
</style>
<title>hangman_game</title>
<rect class="st0" width="360" height="260"/>
<rect x="-8.7" y="207.2" class="st1" width="377.4" height="33"/>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 12.5111 232.7089)" class="st3 st4 st7" font-weight="300">Colombia Infographics</text>
<g>
 <g>
  <g>
   <path class="st5" d="M117.4,133c0.3-0.8,1.2-1.8,1.3-2.5c0.3-1.2-0.5-2.1-0.3-3.2c0.3-1.9,2.4-3.1,2.5-5.2c1.2-0.6,1-0.1,1.9-1.3
    c0.5,0.6,1.4,0.6,1.8,0.9c0.9-1.3,1.9-0.6,3.2-1.6c1.2-0.9,1.5-2.4,2.4-3.5c2.4-2.8,5.4-5,7.6-7.9c-0.9-0.8-1.9-1.3-3.1-1.4
    c0.1-0.8-0.3-1.9-0.1-2.8c-0.4,0.5-1.4,0.8-1.8,1.2c-2-3.1-1-2,0-4.9c0.4-1.2,0.8-3,0.8-4.4c-0.1-2.2-4.1-8.4,1.3-7.5
    c0.2-0.8,0.1-2-0.3-2.7c-1-0.4-1.9-0.6-3-0.7c-0.5-3.1,3.4-2.5,1.1-5.5c-0.2-0.2-1.5-0.1-2.1-0.7c-0.8-0.8-1-1.9-1.3-3
    c-0.8-2.6-0.9-5.2,0.6-7.1c0.5-0.6,1.6-0.5,2.3-1.5c0.7-0.8,0.9-2.5,1.4-3.5c-1.9-1.3-1.9-6.5,1.3-5.6c1.5,0.4,0.5,1.4,1.3,2.4
    c0.2,0.2,1.4,0.3,1.5,0.7c0,0.1,0.1,1.7,0.1,1.7c0.4,1-1.7,1.4,0.9,2.1c1.9,0.5,2.4-0.3,2.2-2.3c-0.2-2.3-3.2-3.5-1.5-6.1
    c4,0.3,3.9-3.3,7.1-5.1c2.9-1.6,6.9-1.6,5.9-6.2c-1.3-0.2-1.9-0.1-2.5,1.1c-0.2-1.8,1.2-3.5,2.2-4.9c0.9-1.3,1.6-3.8,2.4-4.8
    c3-3.4,6.1-2.6,9.8-2.4c-0.7,0.8-1.2,1.7-1.5,2.7c0.5,0.4,1.2,0.6,1.8,0.6c1.1-2.5,1.5-3.4,1.7-6.2c1.8-0.1,2.7-1.2,4.4-1.6
    s3.6,0.2,5.4-0.1c3.7-0.5,6-2.9,9.3-4.4c-0.2-0.7,0-1.4-0.5-2.1c1.1-1.2,5.1-2.6,6.5-3.1c2.7-0.8,5.9-0.3,6.9,2.4
    c-2.2,1.5-5.6,1.6-7.6,3.1s-2.6,3.9-4.9,6c-3.3,3.1-8.6,7.8-8.6,12.7c0,1.2,0.7,2.4,0.3,3.8c-0.3,1.1-2.2,2.9-2.1,3.7
    c0.3,2.4,1.9,0.2,2.8,0.9c1.1,0.9,1.2,2.2,1.8,3.5c1,2.4,3.3,4.9,4.1,7.4c0.7,2.3-0.8,4.9,0.7,6.8c1.6,1.9,6.9,3.8,9.3,3.8
    c1.3-2.6,2.7,0,4,0.1c1.4,0.1,2.5-1.1,4.1-0.9c2.8,0.3,7.3,4.4,9.3,6.1c1,0.9,3.2,3.8,4.4,3.9c0.9,0.1,1.5-1.3,2.5-1.3
    c1.3,0,1.7,1.1,2.8,1.3c1.9,0.3,3.1-0.7,5-1c1.6-0.2,3.3,0.6,5,0c0.3,2.3,3.7,2.6,3.5,5.3c-0.2,2.1-3.8,4.6-5.9,4.4
    c-1,2,0.4,2.2,0.6,3.4c0.2,1.6-0.1,3-0.1,4.6c0,2.7,0,6.3,0.9,9.1c0.3,1,1.7,1.7,1.7,3.4c0,1.4-0.7,2.5-1.3,3.8
    c-0.5,0.9-2.2,2.8-1.6,4.1c0.6,1.3,1.8,1.2,2.8,0c3.1,2.5,3.2,2.8,3.7,6.8c0.2,2.2,0.8,4.8,0.6,7.5c-1.2-1.8-1.4-6.2-3-7.5
    c-2.4-2-4.4,0.7-6.6,1c-1.4,0.2-2.5-0.4-4-0.1c-1.1,0.3-2.3,1.1-3.6,1.3c-2.9,0.4-6.1-0.6-9,0.3c-0.4,1.3-0.5,3.2,0.3,4.4
    c0.9,1.3,2,0.5,2.8,1.2c1.4,1.3,3,4.1,1,5.3c1.2,0,2.2,0.4,2.7,1.3c-3.3,2.7-2.9-0.6-5.4-0.4c-1,0.1-2,1.8-2.7,2.3
    c-1.9,1.4-1.4-1-2,1.8c-0.7,3.6,1.5,3.9,3.5,5.6c1.7,1.5,2.5,4.1,3,6.1c1.6,5.7,1.1,14-2,19c-1.6,2.5-1.6,3.7-2.2,6.6
    c-0.4,1.7-1,5.1-2.9,6c0-0.6-0.5-1.7-0.4-2.5c-1.7-0.3-2.6,0.6-4.3,0.5c-0.9-0.9-0.1-0.8-1.6-1.3c1.7-3.6,5.5-8.1,5.9-12.1
    c-0.4,0.2-1,0.2-1.5,0.6c-1.2-1.6-1.8-2.9-3.8-4c-0.3,0.4-0.9,0.8-1.2,1.1c-0.2-3.1-2.9-0.9-4.7-0.5c-1.4,0.3-1.1,0.3-3,0
    c-1.4-0.2-2.2-0.9-3.7-0.7c-1.7,0.3-2.8,1.8-4.6,1.8c-0.6,0-2.4-0.6-3.2-0.6c-1.6,0-5.4,1.5-5.3-1.2c2.3-0.8,1.8-2,0.6-3.4
    c-0.3-0.4-1.9-0.1-2.1-0.4c-0.7-0.9,0-1.9-0.4-2.8c-0.6-1.5-0.8-2.6-2.5-3.5s-3.2,0.1-4.6-1.4c0.2,0.1,0.5,0.3,0.7,0.3
    c-1.5-1.2-2.4-1.9-3.3-3.5c-1-1.7-1.3-3.8-3.2-4.9c-3.1-1.9-7.2-0.9-9.5-4.4c0.3-0.1,0.8-0.3,1.1-0.4c-1.7-1-10.7-3.4-8.1,1.6
    c-1.5-0.3-3.2-0.1-4.6-0.7c-1.3-0.5-1.9-1.9-3.5-2.4c-1-0.3-3.6,0.5-4.4,0c-1.8-1.4,0.8-2.7,0-4c-0.8-1.4-2.9-0.8-4.1-1.2
    c-1-0.4-2.7-1.5-3.7-2c-2-1.3-4-4.5-6.5-4.7c0.8,1-0.4,0.8-0.4,1.6"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Adding the font-family worked, thanks. But i am having another big problem. Lato still doesn't display in the browsers, only sans-serif does. Lato is displaying when the code snipping is run above though. Man, this is a tough one.

Comment: @InspectorDanno which browsers are you using ?

Comment: here is an example of one I have https://github.com/inspectordanno/inspectordanno.github.io/blob/master/colombia/climate.svg?short_path=202bd73

Comment: The reason it is working in the snippet is because the SVG is inline in the page. I am guessing that you are using the SVG as a stand-alone image referenced by an `<img>` (or `background-image`). Am I right?  If so then read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20577316/svg-font-face-works-in-svg-but-not-when-included-in-a-page

Comment: You are exactly right! I was searching for this for hours and had no idea about the stand-alone imagine problem. The object tag is working beautifully for me. Do you know if this works in all modern browsers?

Comment: I dont see this working, it just fallbacks to font that is after Lato,  so sans-serif default?! Change it to something else and  it will be that, so not Lato, but that other.

Comment: @MarkoBlazekovic you are confirming it's working. If it fallback to sans-serif it means that the property is correctly recognized by the browser which is the main purpose here. If you browser is not showing Lato then the issue is something else (the font is not loaded, the file is broken, etc). Your issue has nothing to do with the way I wrote the code.

Comment: Sorry should have said more later, they are not working as for security reasons you cant import outside fonts into SVGs anymore so you must try to embed them as base64 code or just use fallback. More here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29494271/svg-fonts-are-not-loading-on-a-webpage-using-font-face-in-chrome